# Entity Framework 6.1.1 Async - Wait for Data

Tags: entity-framework

I've got some data that it being written into a table by another application.

I could write some polling code?  But I wondered if there was some way of getting EntityFramwork to handle this.

Something like ...

```
database.MyDbSet.Select(x => x.Id = "my id").WhenAvailableAsync() ?
```

Am I just dreaming? :)

Comment: You are dreaming:)

Comment: So you want it to complete when the data exists? And the data does not exist when you query the db?

Comment: yeah, that's right

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a call via `Task.Run`. For example:

```
public async Task<MyModel> GetSomethingAsync(int id)
{
    return await Task.Run(() => database.MyDbSet.Select(x => x.Id == id));
}
```

That should be able to give you what you want.